# Redirection to file does not work properly

Tags: bash, logs, io-redirection, ping

I have here a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_FILE=ping_result.txt

# declare the target ip addresses
declare -a ips=("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" "YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY")

function print_and_log() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$1" >> $TARGET_FILE 2>&1
}

# loop through all ip addresses
for i in "${ips[@]}"
do
    print_and_log "----- Begin Pinging for $i --- "
    print_and_log "command: ping -c10 $i"
    print_and_log $(ping -c10 $i)
    print_and_log "----- Pinging for $i end ----- "
done
```

My aim is to print the same output into a file and into console. But when I disconnect my operation system from the network, then in the console, I see (for example for the first IP address):

```
----- Begin Pinging for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX --- 
command: ping -c10 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
connect: Network is not reachable

----- Pinging for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX end -----
```

But in the file, I do no see any message, that the Network is not reachable. Why? How can I change my bash script, that I also can see this message in my logging file.

Comment: `print_and_log()` - have you considered using [tee](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee)? Just a suggestion, but it's built to do exactly what that command is doing `echo "hello" | tee -a logfile.log` would add a line to a file in a similar manner to your function.

Comment: I didn't knew `tee`, but thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Network is not reachable" message is printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so it isn't captured by your substitution (`$(ping ...)`). You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` when running `ping`, not when you log:

```
    print_and_log "$(ping -c10 "$i" 2>&1)"
```